# How to configure a session timeout for Grails application?

Tags: session, grails, session-variables, session-timeout

In one of controllers in my Grails application I'm preserving a parameter value in a session variable like this:

```
session.myVariable = params.myValue
```

After that, I can access the saved value from different controllers/GSP-pages as long as I actively use the app. However, if I don't use my app for a while, even though my browser window is still open, the session variable looses it's value.

Does this happens because the session expires? I was under impression that a session lives until the browser window is still open, but apparently I was wrong.

What should I do to ensure all session variables I define in my Grails app don't expire until the browser is closed? Is there any way to set session timeout manually?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Another option would be modifying web.xml. Prior you must call

```
grails install-templates
```

Then edit src/templates/war/web.xml and add/modify after servlet-mapping:

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The value of session-timeout uses minutes as unit.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan! That's *EXACTLY* what I was looking for. I didn't realize I have to explicitly 'install-templates' to get to web.xml. I'm still a n00b in Grails :)

Comment: I want to handle a session timeout as well. I just have a question about this. Configuring this in the web.xml file, what would happend once the session expires and an action from a controller is executed? Would the session.myVariable from @curd0's example will return null? Thanks!

Comment: It this still required for Grails 2.x? I thought `web.xml` was standard in grails apps; why is `install-templates` required?

Comment: @raffian I don't know if it is required, but it does work with grails 2.x (testing grails 2.5.4 here). grails install-templates outputs a lot of stuff but you only have to keep src/templates/war/web.xml, all the rest of src/templates can be deleted.

Answer (score 46):

Fast forward a few years...  For Grails 3.0 set the session timeout with [ServerProperties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.html) in the application configuration file.

**grails-app/conf/application.yml**

```yaml
server:
   session:
      timeout: 3600  #seconds
```

Default value: **1800** seconds (30 minutes)

Verify the timeout for the
[HttpSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/servletapi/jakarta/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)
from a controller using `getMaxInactiveInterval()`:

```
log.println "Timeout: ${session.getMaxInactiveInterval()} seconds"
```

Output -->  **`Timeout: 3600 seconds`**

*Update 1:* Edited for changes to Grails 3.1 configuration.

*Update 2:* For Grails 5, see comment below by *Marc Schmid.*

Comment: Actually it is now server: session: timeout: 3600

Comment: how to disable session timeout? @DemPilafian

Comment: @akiong, I haven't tried it, but according to the documentation, `A zero or negative time indicates that the session should never timeout.`

Comment: For Grails 5 it is `server.servlet.session.timeout=8h`. It changed as the property was change in the underlying spring-boot version. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974955/spring-boot-java-config-set-session-timeout

Answer (score 7):

The current grails (2.x) have a very odd design approach to setting the session timeout. None of the prevailing ideas are great:

1. comment out "//session Timeout"  section the within the WebxmlGrails Plugin and add "sessionConfig.sessionTimeout=" to Config.groovy
2. grails install-templates, remove session-timeout from web.xml, add timeout in WebXmlConfig.groovy
3. wait for a fix. :/

A co-worker came up with the following code that works well for me and will do until a real solution is built into grails core.

Simply add the following to the bottom of your config.groovy file and then set the appropriate timeout.

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
  def webXML = new java.io.File("${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/web.xml")
  webXML.text = webXML.text.replaceFirst("<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>", "<session-timeout>90</session-timeout>")
}
```

My I suggest that the correct solution is to allow a single line in the Config.groovy file:

```
session.timeout = 90;
```

Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean "add the following to the bottom of your **Build**Config.groovy" ?

Comment: Yep, @anders.norgaard is right, BuildConfig is the place where this has an effect.

Answer (score 3):

With Grails 3.1.x session-timeout is deprecated. The correct property in **application.yml** is:

```
server:
    session.timeout: 7200
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure Grails uses the sessions associated with your application container. If you're using Tomcat, for example, you can specify the length of a session.

[Tutorial for changing Tomcat session length.](http://www.chemaxon.com/jchem/doc/admin/tomcat.html)

Comment: Grails does use the container's sessions, but just overriding the default doesn't work because grails will generate a new servlet specific web.xml that will override the default.

Answer (score 1):

here is a better working solution. go you your grails home directory and find 
Example: E:\grails-2.3.8\src\war\WEB-INF\web3.0.template.xml edit the session time out value to desired values:

Example:

        `enter code here`
        90

Answer (score 0):

For Grails 3 application, modifying the `Application.groovy` worked for me:

```
package foo

import grails.boot.GrailsApp
import grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration
import org.apache.catalina.Context
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatContextCustomizer
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean

class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }

    @Bean
    EmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory()

        containerFactory.addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
            @Override
            void customize(Context context) {
                int oneWeekInMinute = 7 * 24 * 60
                context.setSessionTimeout(oneWeekInMinute)
            }
        });

        return containerFactory
    }

}
```