# Increasing request timeout in Tomcat 8.0.32

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have two servers that I use to run application in `Grails 2.4.4` which executes scripts in `Groovy`.

When a script takes more than 45 seconds to execute, the web browser returns internal error exactly on 45 second mark, but the script keeps on going until it is finished. This happens in Chrome, Firefox and Postman (Google App).

I looked through the `conf` directory of `Tomcat` and found `connectionTimeout` property of Connector in `server.xml`, but altering it and restarting the server didn't change anything.

I've also tried adding `keepAliveTimeout="-1"` property to connector, but to no avail. There's session-timeout in `web.xml`, but that obviously can't be it.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705595/how-do-i-implement-a-request-timeout-in-grails) post

Comment: Have you tried to trigger the process by Ajax call? If the process is expected to run such a long time, run it in the background and let user know that process is still running.