# multiple grails app session timeout Issue

Tags: session, tomcat, grails, tomcat7, contextpath

I am using tomcat7 and want to deploy the 2 grails application on it. one with ROOT.war and other with the abc.war. I am getting the session expire Issue on my abc app.

Could you please tell me how to configure the context for both apps so that they should not conflicts.

I tried to set `grails.app.context="/abc"`  in my abc app but unable to solve the Issue ..

IF I run this abc app  alone with name ROOT.war it works fine.

Both apps have some jars and classes common.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem running both apps in the same instance.  For the ROOT app set grails.app.context = '/' in Config.groovy.  For abc you should not have to specify anything in Config.

See [How to configure a session timeout for Grails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907516/how-to-configure-a-session-timeout-for-grails-application) for setting the session timeout.