# Configure session time in Grails

Tags: session, grails-2.0

Has anybody configured session timeout in Grails 2.1? 
Was looking at another post: [How to configure a session timeout for Grails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907516/how-to-configure-a-session-timeout-for-grails-application)
install-templates will add big templates to source code which makes it very difficult to upgrade. Looks like webxml plugin has issues too.
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPWEBXML-9

~Thanks
Abhijith

Comment: You can delete the rest of the templates and just keep the web.xml.

Comment: yes..that is one option..may not be optimum.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in controller:

```
 def minutes = 1
 session.maxInactiveInterval = minutes*60
```

this will set the session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Install the plugin 'Spring Security Core' and configure the resources.groovy file of the plugin. With it you will configure the timeout session, the concurrent sessions and the security for your app.

Comment: we do have spring security core already.  I will try this and also the solution given above.  But, having to install a security plugin to configure session timeout might not be a good idea all the time.