# Issue with grails spring security rest timed out

Tags: grails, spring-security

I want to set timeout for my rest api. I tried different options but it doesn't work.

```
plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.expiration=1800
                    OR
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.memcached.expiration=1800
```

But both options are not works for me.

What I want is the security token have to expire if more than 30 min if it is idle.

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 3 (not sure whether it's the same in Grails 2) you can add the following to your application.yml

`server:
    sessionTimeout: 5400`

The number is the Timeout in seconds, so in this example 90 minutes.

Solution comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30861747/1051514

Comment: Thanks alex. I think your answer is for web application but I am asking for grails spring security rest and also I am using grails 2.4.4.

Comment: In Grails 3 this also works when just using the REST API with spring security.
Sorry that I cannot help more with Grails 2.4.4

Comment: Thanks alex. Actually application timeout is working for me but REST API security token timeout is not working.  Thanks for your response.