# Spring Boot Java Config Set Session Timeout

Tags: spring, session, spring-boot, timeout

How can I configure my (embedded) Tomcat Session Timeout in a Spring Boot Application?

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    se.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60);
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {

}}
```

I have a SessionListener but I have no idea in which class I have to add this Listener to the Context.

Comment: Also useful to know that, according to this article, the setting can't be updated in code and must be done through the properties file as the answers indidcate: https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-session-timeout. From that article: "there is no way to programmatically set the global session timeout"

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should be able to set the `server.session.timeout` in your application.properties file.

ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

**EDIT:**

This property has changed in later versions of Spring Boot to `server.servlet.session.timeout`.

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server.servlet.session.timeout

Comment: server.session.timeout= # Session timeout in seconds.

Comment: In your application.properties
`#session timeout (in secs for spring, in minutes for tomcat server/container)
    server.session.timeout=1`

I tested it and is working!
It turns out that tomcat take the property in minutes

Comment: This only works with the Embedded Tomcat of Spring Boot. When using war-Deployment, you have to add the `SessionListener` from the original question to the project by adding a `@Configuration` annotation on top of it. I would then suggest to use the standard property again by binding it with `@Value("${server.servlet.session.timeout}") Duration timeout` to the `SessionListener` and using that value with `se.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout.toSeconds())`.

Answer (score 89):

`server.session.timeout` in the `application.properties` file is now deprecated. The correct setting is:

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=60s
```

Also note that Tomcat will not allow you to set the timeout any less than 60 seconds. For details about that minimum setting see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7383.

Comment: spring boot 2.0 move

Comment: @user1553728 what?

Comment: Note: in the embeded Tomcat server it is in minutes, so if you set a value smaller that 1 minute, it will have to wait 1 minute for the session to expire.

Comment: I'm using session timeout lower than 60 seconds successfully with a spring boot 2.2.6 and embedded tomcat 9!

Comment: @Daryl server.servlet.session.timeout=60s is not working when I deploy my spring boot(2.2.4) spring security(5.2.1) web application into stand alone tomcat(9).I tried with minute also

Comment: @GhasemSadeghi Are you sure that your sub-60-second timeout actually times out in less than 60 seconds? I tried it today, just for experimentation, with 20s, and the timeout interval seemed to last 1 minute. I think we have embedded Tomcat 9 too. From what I read in the docs, Spring will allow you to set that setting to anything, even with Tomcat, but in the case of Tomcat, it will just round down to the nearest minute, or round up if you are below 1 minute.

Answer (score 52):

- Spring Boot version 1.0: `server.session.timeout=1200`
- Spring Boot version 2.0: `server.servlet.session.timeout=10m`
  NOTE: If a *duration suffix* is not specified, seconds will be used.