# Can you tell me how to configure session timeout in spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE?

Tags: java, spring-boot, session

For my application after specific time the application session has to be expired...
i am using spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE
i tried this way in application.properties file
server.session.timeout=120
But i didn't find it working....

Comment: server.connection-timeout should have a dash and not a period between connection and timeout.

Comment: it is not server.connection, it is server.session.... and i wanmt to know the difference as well between server.session.timeout and server.connection-timeout?

Comment: Aha, might be this. Looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974955/spring-boot-java-config-set-session-timeout

Comment: same thing i have tried Compass.. but it is not working

Comment: i am using embedded tomcat @Mahozad

Comment: Are you testing it with a browser? If so, you need to be aware that your browser will cache and re-send the basic authentication credentials so you get a new session every time. You can mimic this behaviour and see what's happening by using curl

Comment: How to use the curl???

Answer (score 0):

Common servlet container settings can be configured using Spring Environment properties. Usually you would define the properties in your application.properties file.

Session settings: session timeout (server.session.timeout)

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/
section: 27.3.4