# How to set expiration date-time of JSESSION cookie with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cookies, spring-security

I have a web-application based on SpringBoot and using Spring Security for Log-in and Remember-Me, however Remember-Me doesn't work properly and resets after 1 hour of absense of interaction between client and server.

I have checked browser's storage for cookies, remember-me cookie is created and has correct expiration date (1 day after creation). The second cookie: JSESSION has expiration = session. And i think this is causing the problem.

```
+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------+
|    Name     |  Domain   | Path | Expires on                     |
+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------+
| JSESSIONID  | 127.0.0.1 | /    | session                        |
| remember-me | 127.0.0.1 | /    | Tue, 25 Dec 2018 10:28:22 GMT  |
+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------+
```

Here is my spring security configuration for remember-me:

```
.and()
.rememberMe()
.key("secretKey")
.tokenValiditySeconds(60*60*24)
.rememberMeParameter("remember-me");
```

I want that once person is logged in with remember-me option chosen, he/she will not need to log in again for next 24 hours. So is there possibility to set this JSESSION expiration equal to remember-me cookie? I use annotation driven Spring Boot

Comment: @dur Yes, after an hour of inactivity (no sending any requests) if i click on any link I get automatically logged out, and consequently end up seeing login page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSESSIONID` is the cookie that saves your session id. You don't need to set expiration time of `JSESSIONID` as remember-me.

The mechanism will be able to identify the user across multiple sessions – so the first thing to understand is that **Remember Me only kicks in after the session times out**. By default, this happens after 30 minutes of inactivity, but [timeout can be configured](https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-session-timeout) in the web.xml. In Spring boot, you can configure time out with help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974955/spring-boot-java-config-set-session-timeout).

The Remember Me cookie contains the following data:

- username – to identify the logged in principal
- expirationTime – to expire the cookie; default is 2 weeks
- MD5 hash – of the previous 2 values – username and expirationTime, plus the password and the predefined key

So it is enough for remembering user credentials. `JSESSIONID` will delete when session expires or user close the browser. After user comeback he will get new session id without need of logging in again with a valid remember-me cookie.