# How to redirect page to "/login" page if the system is idle for like 5minutes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a running project on spring mvc with login and logout features.I have used the class based annotation (not xml). When I don't used the system for about 5 minutes,then if I try to use the page then,it needs to be redirect to the login page in spring mvc.So I added the new class  `SessionHandler.java` but it is not redirecting me again to login page.How can I handle session of page to goto login screen if user dont access for more than 5minutes?

```
package com.pcs.security.config;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

@Component
public class SessionHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60*5);
        response.sendRedirect("/demo.jsp");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The first AppConfig.class is :

```
package com..config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import com..spring.dbproperties.DbProperties;



@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.*"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/theme/**").addResourceLocations("/theme/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
                = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return jdbcTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public DbProperties dbProperties() {
       DbProperties dbProperties=new DbProperties();
       dbProperties.setDatabaseUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:A/A@A:aaDB");
       return dbProperties;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }


}
```

my pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pcs.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>PCA</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- Mysql Connector -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons Fileupload -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL Dependency -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- JSP Dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an application.properties file in your app...
Add this line there-

server.servlet.session.timeout=5m

This will invalidate the current session for your application.
Thanks to this link from stackoverflow- [Spring Boot Java Config Set Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974955/spring-boot-java-config-set-session-timeout)