# How to force session to expire after specified time?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Using Spring-boot security I would like to force to expiry logged user session after specific amount of time (e.g. 15 minutes).

Since `JSESSIONID` cookie is used to identify logged user, I would expect this cookie has to be forced to expiry. If this is correct, how to do that? If not, what is the correct approach?

my current `SecurityConfig`:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").clearAuthentication(true).invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).eraseCredentials(true);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually the session expiry is set in App Server, or in WebApp layer in web.xml

Comment: use _spring.session.timeout = 900_ via application.properties

Comment: @DirkDeyne I tried to set `spring.session.timeout = 10`. Then I logged sending authenticated request to obtain JSESSIONID cookie. Then tried to send request without authorization, just using JSESSIONID to authenticate. Requests were identified as authorized and returned data even if timeout expired already. JSESSIONID cookie expiry was set to ca 19 years in the future.

Comment: @Radouxca sorry my bad, try _server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age_ ?

Comment: @DirkDeyne  _server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age_ worked well. However, does this property set max-age for all cookies, or just for session cookie?

Comment: if you create extra cookies, you can set the expiration date via ```somecookie.setMaxAge(...)```

Answer (score 0):

I found related question here: [Spring Boot Java Config Set Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974955/spring-boot-java-config-set-session-timeout).

Using `server.servlet.session.timeout=60s` worked well to force user session expire and no requirement to touch cookie