# Possible to set a maximum active session duration in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, session

I know its possible to implement a maximum inactivity interval for the user's session using something like:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40975566

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=1800s
```

Which will invalidate the user's session if they are inactive for 30 minutes.

But if the user remains active, I would like to invalidate the session after say 12 hours. Is this possible using some sort of SpringBoot annotation or mechanism?

Ideally I'd like to avoid some custom solution, but if thats the only approach, so be it.