# Why is my used memory of my vaadin application not going down?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory, vaadin

I have a vaadin flow application (vaadin 23.3.3 and spring boot 2.7.0) and i see a strange behaviour in the used memory.
When my application starts the memory used is low as expected. When our users are starting to use the application the memory is going up but never going down again.

I tested this by simulating multiple users that just login and load the first vaadin page, after that they just close their browser window.
The memory is going up and stays at a higher level see picture:
[image: java melody used memory]

The red circle is when i started to simulate users logging in.

I took a heap dump and looked at the dominator tree see picture:
[image: dominator tree]

Is there something that we need to trigger manually to remove our views from the memory?

Comment: The fact that a user closes the browser doesn't cleanup session resources. Default session timeout is 30 minutes, so the session storage will be cleaned up after 30 minutes after the last activity.

Comment: @M.Deinum is right here. I have a blog post in queue that discusses this "issue" as well. If you want to eagerly collect the view, you could upgrade to Vaadin 24.1.0.alpha5, which contains my PR that makes a "beacon request" on window close so that the UI can be collected.

An easier approach for testing with the current version would be to [set session timeout to 1 minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974955/spring-boot-java-config-set-session-timeout) for testing and wait a bit.

Comment: The chart shows a full day, i would expect the used memory to go down 30min after my test? (because of the sessions storage that would be cleaned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with Vaadin 23.3.3 and the tooltip. You should update the version to the latest Vaadin 23.3.11, the issue is fixed.

Comment: Indeed, after upgrading to Vaadin 23.3.12 the problem is resolved